# Can anyone define a recursive function to solve this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose you are given a nested list such as a=[1,2,3,4,[5,6],[7,[8,9],10]] How to define a function which prints
all the component lists separately like printing every list including the main list. Answer should be (order is not important)

```
[1,2,3,4,[5,6],[7,[8,9],10]]
[5,6]
[7,[8,9],10]
[8,9]
```

Comment: Please read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1):

```py
a=[1,2,3,4,[5,6],[7,[8,9],10]]

def printlist(lst):
  print(lst)
  for item in lst:
    if type(item) is list:
      printlist(item)

printlist(a)
```

It's a simple function, print the list when its called, then go over each list item and check if it's a list, if so call the function on that item.

I'm using the `is` operator here, this checks whether two variables point to the same object in memory. You can also use the `isinstance(value, type)` function.

Comment: Thanks, my assignment was due in 5 hours and I was stuck with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the list and check if the content is of type list. If the content is of type list, you should print it and iterate over it and the rest of the main list.

Something like this, without for loop:

```py
 def recur(x):
    ...:     if len(x) == 0:
    ...:         return
    ...:     if isinstance(x[0], list):
    ...:         print(x[0])
    ...:         recur(x[1::])
    ...:         recur(x[0])
    ...:     else:
    ...:         recur(x[1::])
```